# Retrieving Content Uri using File Provider fails

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I have spent days reading the docs and following various tutorials for this but I am getting errors whatever I do. I am trying to save an image in Internal Storage and then convert it to a content Uri so that I can use the system crop and resize function. If anyone could spot where my code is wrong I would be very grateful:

**Main Activity:**

```
new Thread(() -> {
try {
    String temp = "temp";

    //Convert bitmap to byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();

    //Write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(temp, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(bitmapData);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    //Convert file to contentUri
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), temp);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "@string/file_provider_authority", file);
    intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/jpg");

    intent = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CROP);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}).start();
```

**Manifest:**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**file_provider_paths.xml**:

```
<paths>
<files-path
    path="/" name="temp" />
```

**strings.xml**:

```
<resources>
<string name="file_provider_authority"
    translatable="false">com.me.wallpaper_app.provider
</string>
```

**Error:**

```
    W/System.err(12162): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    W/System.err(12162):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:604)
    W/System.err(12162):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:578)
    W/System.err(12162):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:416)
    W/System.err(12162):    at com.me.wallpaper_app.MainActivity$1$1.lambda$onResourceReady$0$MainActivity$1$1(MainActivity.java:82)
    W/System.err(12162):    at com.me.wallpaper_app.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$1$1$Xm-7yym42zTgTZOFP5GGtbF6p2U.run(Unknown Source:4)
    W/System.err(12162):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"@string/file_provider_authority"` is not how you reference string resources in Java. Use `getString(R.string.file_provider_authority)`.

**UPDATE**: Based on the comments, the second major problem is that the consumer of this content isn't using the MIME type from the `Intent`, but instead is calling `getType()` on a `ContentResolver` to get the type from the `ContentProvider`. In this case, that is your `FileProvider`, and `FileProvider` only knows how to work with file extensions and converting those to MIME types. So, using `temp.jpeg` gave `FileProvider` the information necessary to return the proper MIME type.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this! And now I am getting this error: "Cannot use passed URI to set wallpaper; check that the type returned by ContentProvider matches image/*". But I did set the data and type to image. Hmm...

Comment: @user9480972: Try `"image/jpeg"` instead of `"image/jpg"` for the MIME type.

Comment: @user9480972: Change `setFlags()` to `addFlags()` in both places. Right now, your second `setFlags()` call overwrites the result from the first one.

Comment: Ok, done. I am obviously doing something else wrong because this is what I am now getting: "I/System.out(20634): Image Data and Type = Intent { dat=content://com.me.wallpaper_app.provider/files/temp typ=image/* flg=0x3 }
I/System.out(20634): Image Uri = content://com.me.wallpaper_app.provider/files/temp
W/System.err(20634): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use passed URI to set wallpaper; check that the type returned by ContentProvider matches image/* Should I call "temp" differently? Like "image" for instance?

Comment: @user9480972: Use `image/jpeg`, not `image/*`, in the `Intent`. I also suggest switching from `openFileOutput()` to creating a `FileOutputStream` directly using the same `File` object that you use with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. Then, use `compress()` directly with that `FileOutputStream` (getting rid of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` intermediary). Finally, use `temp.jpg` or `temp.jpeg` for the filename, in case the wallpaper stuff is ignoring the MIME type in the `Intent` and asking `FileProvider` for the MIME type`.

Comment: Using "temp.jpeg" for the filename did the trick. Will adapt my code to what you suggest too. Really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
      Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, R.string.file_provider_authority, file);
```

**Also Change**

```
    <paths>
    <files-path
    path="/" name="temp" />
```

**To**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```